# using the C API requires #include <tango-api/public-api.h>

Tags: c, api, google-project-tango, tango, c-api

I'm trying to use the Tango C API, but in all the files in the SDK, there are references to `#include <tango-api/public-api.h>`. I have done some research and cannot find where to get the public tango API or what it is. Shouldn't the SDK include all the required header files?

What is the public API and how do I get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: That wasn't any more relevant to the question. It's ironic that you would comment to a first-timer by posting a simple link to a "How to properly ask". You would think you would apply the same principles to answers! Anyways, I modified the question, hope it helps :S

Comment: @DavidMenard: You didn't escape the include statement with backslashes, which SO use to indicate code snippets. The `<>` in the statement then rendered the filename invisible -- which made your question a bit confusing. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the header is located at tango-example-c/tango-sdk/include.

Credit for the answer to @JasonGuo - he put the answer on G+ - this is just housekeeping